# angular json handling in ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Hi can anybody help me for this,
 I am want to display div 'entry' but somehow condition is not working.I want to display div according to blog_type.How to do?

Here is my js code:

```
        app.controller('blog_controller', function ($scope, $http) {
                        $scope.blog=[
                            {
                                 middle:{
                                    title:'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
                                    full_img:'1.jpg',
                                    content:'Asperiores',
                                    thumb:'1.jpg',
                                    date:'10th Feb 2014',
                                    blog_type:'Image'                   
                                },
                                middle:{
                                    title:'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
                                    full_img:'1.jpg',
                                    content:'Asperiores, sque.',
                                    thumb:'1.jpg',
                                    date:'5th Feb 2014',
                                    blog_type:'Video'
                                },
                           }         
                        ];
                    });
```

Here is my html code:
In ng-if iam checking value of blog_type and display div but the condition becoming true for Video only.

```
          <div id="posts" class="small-thumbs alt"  ng-repeat="b in blog">
                  <div class="entry clearfix" ng-if="b.middle.blog_type == 'Image'">
                              <div class="entry-image">

                                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `$scope.blog` object declaration is wrong, you are declaring one object with duplicate properties. For your scenario you have to declare objects of array.

here is the valid code segment

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('blog_controller', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.blog = [{

    title: 'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
    full_img: '1.jpg',
    content: 'Asperiores',
    thumb: '1.jpg',
    date: '10th Feb 2014',
    blog_type: 'Image'
  }, {
    title: 'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
    full_img: '1.jpg',
    content: 'Asperiores, sque.',
    thumb: '1.jpg',
    date: '5th Feb 2014',
    blog_type: 'Video'

  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" , ng-controller="blog_controller">
  <div id="posts" class="small-thumbs alt" ng-repeat="b in blog">
    <div class="entry clearfix" ng-if="b.blog_type == 'Image'">
      <div class="entry-image">
          test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.blog` value is incorrect. First of all, it is an array of a single object. Furthermore, the object itself has multiple `middle` parameters, which is should throw error if you run js in strict mode. `use strict` on top. What you need to do is to change the `$scope.blog` to following;

```js
                        $scope.blog=[
                          {
                                    title:'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
                                    full_img:'1.jpg',
                                    content:'Asperiores',
                                    thumb:'1.jpg',
                                    date:'10th Feb 2014',
                                    blog_type:'Image'                   
                                },
                                    title:'THIS IS A STANDARD POST WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE',
                                    full_img:'1.jpg',
                                    content:'Asperiores, sque.',
                                    thumb:'1.jpg',
                                    date:'5th Feb 2014',
                                    blog_type:'Video'
                                },        
                        ];
```

This is new html code:

```html
          <div id="posts" class="small-thumbs alt"  ng-repeat="b in blog">
                  <div class="entry clearfix" ng-if="b.blog_type == 'Image'">
                              <div class="entry-image">

                                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```